# I want to create a macro to remove the space After the String in the range. Tried Trim and doesn't do anything

Tags: excel, vba

I want to remove the extra spaces after the text "Denver Health  "   into "Denver Health" for the range in column A.
**input:**

*Column A*

```
"Denver Health Hospital  "
"Pueblo Hospital "
```

**output:**

*Column A*

```
"Denver Health Hospital"
"Pueblo Hospital"
```

I have tried that code but it removes all the spaces

```
Sub SpaceKiller()
   Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns("A").Replace _
      what:=" ", _
      Replacement:="", _
      SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
      MatchCase:=True
End Sub
```

Another attempt was

```
Sub trim()
Dim r As String

r = RTrim(Range("A2:A"))
End Sub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question with your code attempt. See [reprex]. In other words, please show *how* you tried `Trim`.

Comment: Are you sure those "spaces" are really spaces?  Copy/paste from other sources (particularly from the web) often brings over characters which look like spaces but are not.  Eg. "non-breaking space" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space

Comment: Hi Tim, its actual space after the hospital name "Denver Health  ". I have also tried Rtrim, Trim Function and trim and didn't do anything. This code works but removes all the space instead of the space in the end. I am beginner in VBA thank you

Comment: Try please the next way to identify what character is and then use it to replace: `Debug.Print Asc(Right("Denver Health ", 1))`. But use the exactly string downloaded from the source you use. What does it return in `Immediate Window`? If not 32, it is anther character which can be used for replacing, instead of " ". I mean `Chr(returned number)`...

Comment: I added my other attempt using trim and nothing happens

Comment: `r = RTrim(Range("A2:A"))` - first, `A2:A` is not a valid range. Then, that doesn't actually change the values in column A.

Comment: Hi Ben, Do you know the right way to do it. Thank you

Comment: Please, try `Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean (Trim("Denver Health "))`.

Answer (score 1):

This will get the trailing spaces..

```
Sub TrimTrailingSpaces()

    Dim LR As Long 'Use Long as Integer can only handle 32,767
    Dim myRng As Range 'I am going to name the used range
    Dim ws As Worksheet 'Declare worksheet as variable
    Dim cll As Range 
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") 'Want to be specific on the worksheet used
    
    LR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Find the last row in Col A.  Do not include the whole column of over 1 million cells
    
    Set myRng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(LR, 1)) 'Declare the range used
    
    For Each cll In myRng 'cll is a Cell in a Collection of Cells in a Range that we defined
        cll = RTrim(cll) 'Looping through, modify each cell
    Next cll 'Go to the next Cell
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I assumed the quotes were for illustration to show the text contents

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly. I am beginner can you add notes to explain the parts. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Comments added next to each line

Comment: Your the best thank you alot

Answer (score 0):

You can write own function to delete all additional spaces from string. allow only one space

```
Function Remove2Spaces(text As String) As String
Dim i_Len As Integer
Dim ReturnText As String

i_Len = Len(text)
For i = 1 To i_Len
    If Mid(text, i, 1) = " " Then
        If Mid(text, i + 1, 1) = " " Then
            text = Mid(text, 1, i) & Mid(text, i + 2)
            i = i - 1
        End If
    End If
Next i
Remove2Spaces = text
End Function
```

to get result place inside sub like below

```
sub Test()
MsgBox Remove2Spaces(ActiveSheet.Range("A3"))
end sub
```